# Entity Framework one context many databases

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-4

In my app, I have one context but the user can select one of many databases during login. All these databases are based on the same context and their connection strings are configured in web.config.

I have a class that caches the user details:

```
public class UserDetais
{
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

Once the user logs in, a new UserDetails object is added to the cache for later requests.

On receiving further requests, the controller gets the user's details from the cache and passes them on to the service, for example:

```
public class CustomerTypeController : ApiController
{
    private readonly ICustomerTypeService customerTypeService;

    public CustomerTypeController(ICustomerTypeService customerTypeService)
        : base(logService)
    {
        this.customerTypeService = customerTypeService;
    }

    protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(controllerContext);

        var token = controllerContext.Request.Properties["token"] as string;
        var details = UserCache.Get(token);

        customerTypeService.SetUserDetails(details);
    }    
 }
```

The service then sets the user details in the unit of work, and at this stage, the unit of work creates a new context based on the user's connection string.

This solution works, however it looks a little hacky. Is there a better way to implement a one-context-many-databases strategy?